# Send data from php to JS for google motion chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw a MotionChart with data coming from a XMLHttpRequest. If data for MotionChart is hardcoded like the following example it is properly displayed.

```
function drawMotChart(dataObject) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
    data.addRows([
      ['Apples',  new Date (1988,0,1), 1000, 300, 'East'],
      ['Oranges', new Date (1988,0,1), 1150, 200, 'West'],
      ['Bananas', new Date (1988,0,1), 300,  250, 'West'],
      ['Apples',  new Date (1989,6,1), 1200, 400, 'East'],
      ['Oranges', new Date (1989,6,1), 750,  150, 'West'],
      ['Bananas', new Date (1989,6,1), 788,  617, 'West']
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height:300});
}
```

But I want to get data from a php. So I tried the following. In the webpage header I have:

```
function SendParameters() {
    document.getElementById("chart_div").innerHTML ="";

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("ShowAjax").innerHTML = "Just to see the incomming data:<br>"+xmlhttp.responseText;
                DataFromAjax = xmlhttp.responseText;
                drawMotChart(DataFromAjax);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "L_GetDataAjax.php?Group=Main", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}

function drawMotChart(dataObject) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
    data.addRows([dataObject]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height:300});
}
```

And the `L_GetDataAjax.php` file is like this:

**PHP**

```
$DataToSend="['Apples',  new Date (1988,0,1), 1000, 300, 'East'],
             ['Oranges', new Date (1988,0,1), 1150, 200, 'West'],
             ['Bananas', new Date (1988,0,1), 300,  250, 'West'],
             ['Apples',  new Date (1989,6,1), 1200, 400, 'East'],
             ['Oranges', new Date (1989,6,1), 750,  150, 'West'],
             ['Bananas', new Date (1989,6,1), 788,  617, 'West']";
echo $DataToSend;
```

But in this case there is no Chart.

So my question is: How can I add the data from a XMLHttpRequest to the chart?

Comment: 1. build the array with PHP, send as JSON (i.e. `json_encode()` and `header("Content-Type: application/json");`) 2. in JS, use `JSON.parse()` to turn received JSON into an Object which you can pass to `addRows()`  (or keep it "dirty" and just parse in JS, but you'll have to actually create the dates using JS))

Comment: Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/708qsjt7/ showing how to send the date as array and create `Date` objects on the client. Doesn't work though, but neither does Google's own jsfiddle.

Comment: @ChrisG It worked!! It take me a while (not an expert), but now is working. Thanks a lot!!